# Sorting multiple values by ascending and descending

Tags: ruby, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of objects based upon different attributes. Some of those attributes I would like to sort in ascending order and some in descending order. I have been able to sort by ascending or descending but have been unable to combine the two.

Here is the simple class I am working with:

```
class Dog
  attr_reader :name, :gender

  DOGS = []

  def initialize(name, gender)
    @name = name
    @gender = gender
    DOGS << self
  end

  def self.all
    DOGS
  end

  def self.sort_all_by_gender_then_name
    self.all.sort_by { |d| [d.gender, d.name] }
  end
end
```

I can then instantiate some dogs to be sorted later.

```
@rover = Dog.new("Rover", "Male")
@max = Dog.new("Max", "Male")
@fluffy = Dog.new("Fluffy", "Female")
@cocoa = Dog.new("Cocoa", "Female")
```

I can then use the sort_all_by_gender_then_name method.

```
Dog.sort_all_by_gender_then_name
=> [@cocoa, @fluffy, @max, @rover]
```

The array it returns includes females first, then males, all sorted by name in ascending order.

But what if I want to have gender be descending, and then name ascending, so that it would be males first and then sorted by name ascending. In this case:

```
=> [@max, @rover, @cocoa, @fluffy]
```

Or, if I wanted it by gender ascending, but name descending:

```
=> [@fluffy, @cocoa, @rover, @max]
```

When sorting numerical values, you can prepend a - to make it sort in reverse. However, I have been unable to find a way to do this with strings. Any help or ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using `.sort` instead of `.sort_by`:

```
dogs = [
  { name: "Rover", gender: "Male" },
  { name: "Max", gender: "Male" },
  { name: "Fluffy", gender: "Female" },
  { name: "Cocoa", gender: "Female" }
]

# gender asc, name asc
p(dogs.sort do |a, b|
  [a[:gender], a[:name]] <=> [b[:gender], b[:name]]
end)

# gender desc, name asc
p(dogs.sort do |a, b|
  [b[:gender], a[:name]] <=> [a[:gender], b[:name]]
end)

# gender asc, name desc
p(dogs.sort do |a, b|
  [a[:gender], b[:name]] <=> [b[:gender], a[:name]]
end)
```

Output:

```
[{:name=>"Cocoa", :gender=>"Female"}, {:name=>"Fluffy", :gender=>"Female"}, {:name=>"Max", :gender=>"Male"}, {:name=>"Rover", :gender=>"Male"}]
[{:name=>"Max", :gender=>"Male"}, {:name=>"Rover", :gender=>"Male"}, {:name=>"Cocoa", :gender=>"Female"}, {:name=>"Fluffy", :gender=>"Female"}]
[{:name=>"Fluffy", :gender=>"Female"}, {:name=>"Cocoa", :gender=>"Female"}, {:name=>"Rover", :gender=>"Male"}, {:name=>"Max", :gender=>"Male"}]
```

Basically, this is doing something similar to negating numbers (as you mentioned in the question), by swapping the property to the other element if it needs to be sorted in descending order.

Comment: I have a doubt,that I still not understand about `enum#sort` is - how `<=>` results help the enum to get sorted? how the 3 values `-1,0,+1` are helping on enum to get sorted?

Comment: @Priti, it's similar to what most language's (C, C++) sort function has - if you want the first parameter to be ranked before the second, return +1, if you want them to appear in the same order as they were in the list, then 0, otherwise you want the second parameter to be before, return -1.

Comment: @Priti, let me know if I misunderstood your doubt.

Comment: thanks.. Yes that's I was wondering.. yes now I got how it works actually.

Answer (score 1):

This `ReversedOrder` mixin can help you accomplish the mixed direction sorts on seperate attributes, using `sort_by`:

```
module ReversedOrder
  def <=>(other)
    - super
  end
end
```

Use example:

```
dogs = [
  { name: "Rover", gender: "Male" },
  { name: "Max", gender: "Male" },
  { name: "Fluffy", gender: "Female" },
  { name: "Cocoa", gender: "Female" }
]

dogs.sort_by {|e| [e[:gender], e[:name]] }
=> [{:name=>"Cocoa", :gender=>"Female"},
 {:name=>"Fluffy", :gender=>"Female"},
 {:name=>"Max", :gender=>"Male"},
 {:name=>"Rover", :gender=>"Male"}]

dogs.sort_by {|e| [e[:gender].dup.extend(ReversedOrder), e[:name]] }
=> [{:name=>"Max", :gender=>"Male"},
 {:name=>"Rover", :gender=>"Male"},
 {:name=>"Cocoa", :gender=>"Female"},
 {:name=>"Fluffy", :gender=>"Female"}]
```

Note: Be careful to `dup` the reversed element. Without that, you will mixin the comparison inverter to the actual object instead of just the key being made for `sort_by` and it will forever produce reversed comparisons.

Comment: Won't performance be really bad because of the multiple `extend`?